# React native fbsdk not working with Facebook app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

React native fbsdk is not working if facebook own app is installed on the device. i am using

import { LoginButton, AccessToken, GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager, LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

for facebook login. It is working fine but as there is a facebook default app in the device. facebook login not works. how can i resolve this. so if facebook app will be installed still my app facebook will still work.